# ReactJS: Filter operation

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem about the use of filter. In my componentDidMount I have:

```
    async componentDidMount(){
            window.scrollTo(0, 0)
            this._resetForm(true)
            const id = this.props.match.params._id;
//there is the problem
            const currentWarehouse = this.props.user.db
            console.log("currentWarehouse", currentWarehouse) // this prints "warehouse"
            const searchedProduct = this.props.products.Products.warehouse.filter((e) => {return e._id == id})
            const product = _.pick(searchedProduct[0], ['Anagraphics', 'Code', 'Categories'])
            this.setState({product});

            this.props.initialize(product);
```

now if I use the value "warehouse" directly in the const searchedProduct it works. While if I use:

```
const searchedProduct = this.props.products.Products.currentWarehouse.filter I received the error:
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

I need to use the second form, how can I do??

Comment: as the error says `this.props.products.Products.warehouse` may not be defined

Comment: This works correctly, if I find the word "warehouse" from the variable: const currentWarehouse = this.props.user.db (that the console log prints "warehouse") it does't works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the `.` notation you use literal values (*what you type refers to the name of the keys of the object*). If you want to use a variable you need to use the `[]` notation, ie. `Products[currentWarehouse]`.

```
const currentWarehouse = this.props.user.db;
const searchedProduct = this.props.products.Products[currentWarehouse].filter((e) => {return e._id == id});
```